# Firebase Functions predeploy: ignore folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

In my Firebase Functions folder, I have test code disliked by Lint: keywords like "async" and "await" for integration tests.

It's causing problem when deploy. I can disable Lint but I don't want to. Is there a way that I can exclude the test folder for predeploy? My firebase.json:

```
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
```

Comment: async/await isn't available in node 6.  Supports starts in node 8.  Have you configured your local environment, project, and Cloud Functions deployment correctly?

Comment: I can use node 8. But adding "engines": { "node": "8" } doesn't seem work for me. Is there document on how to config it?

Comment: What is your local environment's node version?  That has to be >= 8 as well.  `node --version`.  Also please update your question with the exact error and lines of code that are relevant here.  Without seeing details of exactly what you're seeing, it's hard to know know what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did that and created a new question since that's a separate issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113864/cannot-use-node-8-for-firebase-functions