# Cannot use Node 8 for Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I want to use Node 8 for Firebase Functions. I have added the "engines": { "node": "8" } line to my package.json. This is how it looks like:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "^2.15.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And I have the right version of tools.

npm info firebase-functions version

```
2.1.0
```

npm info firebase-tools version

```
6.2.2
```

node --version

```
v8.13.0
```

However, when deploying the functions, Link still complains about async and await:

```
7:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token function
```

This is minimal code that reproduces the issue. db.query() returns a Promise.

```
const db = require("../db");

run().then(result => {
  console.log("done");
});

async function run() {
    return db.query("select * from events");
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the *entire, minimal code* that reproduces the problem, not just one line.

Comment: FYI there are much newer major versions of eslint and eslint-plugin-promise.  Have you tried updating all your dependencies?

Comment: does the firebase cli show whether you are deploying a node6 or 8 function when you are deploying?

Comment: er do you mean `lint` still complain when you typed `Link`?

Comment: Doug, Thanks for the help. I have updated it with the entire code. Also updated eslint and eslint plugin but it didn't help.

Comment: William, thanks for the help. Yes Link was a typo. Unfortunately firebase cli doesn't show which version of node I am deploying.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the [helpful writeup](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee).  I am still having an issue upgrading to Node 10 - any tips? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644107/cant-upgrade-cloud-functions-to-node-10

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden .eslintrc.json file under functions/. You need to update the ecmaVersion field too.