# Can't upgrade Cloud Functions to Node 10

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Tried upgrading from Node 8 to Node 10 ([instructions are simple](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee)), but still get errors when attempting to run eg. "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"

I'm using most updated tooling (Firebase Tools: 8.9.2) and .  I'm not running a linter.

Any ideas?

```
//relevant files in package.json:
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
  },
}
```

Code comparison

```
//previous code in node 8, does not error
exports.A = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 22 * * *")
  .onRun(() => bigQueryDump());
```

```
//code in node 10, throws error
export const A = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 22 * * *")
  .onRun(() => bigQueryDump());
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code that is giving the issue

Comment: Were you not getting the errors when the functions were on Node 8?

Comment: Can you share the code with the "export" part?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere updated!  I was not getting errors before.

Comment: Does your previous node 8 code give an error in node 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

You changed your code from `exports.A = ...` to `export const A`.

In either [the medium post you shared](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee) nor the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?authuser=0#upgrade-node10) is mentioned that this change is required.

Furthermore, the error suggests that it is not understanding `export`.

Changing this back to `exports.A` should fix that issue.

You can see the [examples in the docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/a3e0e4ae1dae5c585792ef17fde6472244f6277a/functions/helloworld/index.js#L61) that this is still the format for node 10.